# Remove class based if a cookie is set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a particular class from all external urls on a page, only if a cookie has been set. I have the below code but doesn't work as expected.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var vLink = jQuery('.external a');
    if (localStorage.getItem("cookiename")) {
        vLink.removeClass('myclass');
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for a *cookie* or for an item in *local storage*?  They are two different things.

Comment: I am looking for the name of a particular cookie using only jquery

Comment: I couldn't find an answer purely with a jquery method using no plugins..

Comment: Then the problem is that your code isn't looking for a cookie, it's looking in local storage.  Refer to the linked duplicate for information on reading a cookie in JavaScript.  (Which, incidentally, is unrelated to jQuery.)

Comment: ok thank you but can this be done with jQuery without using JavaScript ?

Comment: No, jQuery itself can not be used without JavaScript.